# curl returns 400 bad request without quotes

Tags: php, shell, curl

```
curl -v 'something.com:12684/CAB/keyfile?r=ORE_0&t=VOD&p=1'
```

returns a 200, but using

```
curl -v something.com:12684/CAB/keyfile?r=ORE_0&t=VOD&p=1
```

returns a 400. Why do the quotes matters?

Comment: 1) That's how shells work. 2) You can use escapeshellarg() and PHP will do it for you 3) You don't need command-line curl anyway, PHP has built-in curl functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your URL has characters your shell recognizes as special. Most likely, the `&`, which is the signal to UNIX-ish shells to place the command in the background. So you effectively are executing three commands:

```
curl -v something.com:12684/CAB/keyfile=?r=ORE_0
t=VOD
p=1
```

You're not seeing any shell error output, because the last two are valid shell constructs.

Always quote your arguments. If in PHP, use [`escapeshellarg`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). Better, use the [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) built-in or a third-party library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/).