# Get source code of this website

Tags: bash, url, curl, cookies, lynx

I would like to get some data from some books I want to buy. But for that I need to get the source code of the page and I can not.

A exemplo URL is:

```
http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloDetalle.do?sidTitul=793927&action=busquedaInicial&noValidating=true&POS=0&MAX=50&TOTAL=0&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es
```

I'm testing with various possibilities in curl, wget, lynx, accepting cookies, etc.

```
  # curl http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloDetalle.do?sidTitul=793927&action=busquedaInicial&noValidating=true&POS=0&MAX=50&TOTAL=0&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es
[1] 1680
[2] 1681
[3] 1682
[4] 1683
[5] 1684
[6] 1685
[7] 1686
[8] 1687
```

If I see the headers, I marked a 302

```
   curl -I 'http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloDetalle.do?sidTitul=793927&action=busquedaInicial&noValidating=true&POS=0&MAX=50&TOTAL=0&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es'
**HTTP/1.1 302 Movido tempor�lmente**
Date: Fri, 08 Jul 2016 09:31:07 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: Servlet 2.4; JBoss-4.2.1.GA (build: SVNTag=JBoss_4_2_1_GA date=200707131605)/Tomcat-5.5
Location: http://www.mcu.es/paginaError.html
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

The same goes for me if I use '', "", \? \&, wget, lynx -source, accept cookies, etc.The only thing I get download error page (where I send the code 302)

You know how I can download the source code of the URL that I put an example? (Bash, php, python, perl ...)

Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi.

I tried the curl you tell me and just download my another different page, not that I would like.


curl -Lkg "http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloDetalle.do?sidTitul=907145&action=busquedaInicial&noValidating=true&POS=0&MAX=50&TOTAL=0&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es" 2>/dev/null | wc

    243    Lines.  ..... grep "1973" -->don't exist.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [curl returns 400 bad request without quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37811962/curl-returns-400-bad-request-without-quotes)

Answer (score 0):

The page you are looking for isn't available. Try visiting the website on your browser, you will still not be able to get the information you need. If you need the source you need to give the -L flag and it will get the source code.

Comment: Yes, it is a page that has a time session. Would have to do another search to access a book.

http://www.mcu.es/webISBN/tituloSimpleFilter.do?cache=init&prev_layout=busquedaisbn&layout=busquedaisbn&language=es

thx